# Installing certificate installed through MMC for a service account

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate, windows-service, x509, mmc

*(**Disclaimer:** I have posted this question [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62582887/4375327), but from a developer point of view. I tried to rewrite the question to fit ServerFault conditions)*

A custom service has to log on a remote server through an HTTPS connection, so with an SSL certificate (Windows 2008 Server SP2).

I followed [Microsoft's instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc780545(v=ws.10)) to install a certificate for a service account with MMC. The certificate is (self-signed) installed in **Trusted Root** Certification Authorities Certificate store. So I added a Certificate Snap-in added the certificate for the service account. Then I saved the console file somewhere, but I don't know if it's useful (I suppose the changes are effective immediately?).

The certificate is visible in the registry (`<ServiceName>` is the name of the service):

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\ Services\<ServiceName>\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\<digitalFootprint>
```

However, the service doesn't find the certificate (the store is assumed to be of type X509).

I experienced a similar problem when trying to install a certificate for a user with **certmgr.msc**. I had to log as the user, install it through **Internet Explorer** to make it work.

Did I miss something?

Comment: The code is opening the user certificate store, but you installed the certificate in the machine store.

Comment: @GregAskew, thanks. Then how to install the certificate so the service account retrieves it? I selected "Service account" in [Microsoft instructions page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc780545(v=ws.10)) (mentionned in my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Crypt32's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62683105/4375327) in the [StackOverflow version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62582887/4375327) of this question, the problem is due to .NET Api limitations: it "doesn't support certificate lookup in service account stores.".